# Using 2 CASE statements in a query

Tags: oracle11g

I recently run into a problem of using 2 CASE statements in a select statement for viewing purpose.

Suppose I have a table called login (emp_num, log_in_date, log_in_time).

Note that Log_in_date will contain date in 'DD-MM-YY' format, while log_in_time will be formatted as '24HH:MM:SS'

Here are the 2 cases when run separately:

**Get count of login attempts based on Time of the day**

```
select  count(*) as "Logins", Log_Time as "Time Of Day"
from (select(
CASE

when to_char(login.log_in_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') > '12:00:00' 
and to_char(login.log_in_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') <= '18:00:00' then 'Afternoon'

when to_char(login.log_in_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') > '18:00:00' 
and to_char(login.log_in_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') < '6:00:00' then 'Evening'

else 'Morning'
end ) as Log_Time from login)
group by  Log_Time;
```

**Result:**

```
Logins Time of Day            
   ___
13265   morning                   
16115   afternoon                 
6709   evening
```

This is the second query that displays the count of login attempts for each semester:

```
select  count(*) as "Logins", Semester
from (select(
CASE

when login.log_in_date >= '15-AUG-09' and login.log_in_date <= '18-DEC-09'    then 'Fall 2009'
when login.log_in_date >= '1-JAN-10' and login.log_in_date <= '15-MAY-10' then 'Spring 2010'

end ) as Semester from login)

group by  Semester;
```

**Result:**

```
Logins SEMESTER  
---------- -----------
16511 Spring 2010  
19578 Fall 2009
```

My Question is, how do I combine these 2 CASE statements in a select statement so that the result will be as following:

```
  Logins Time of Day               Semester
```

---

```
  8292 afternoon                 Fall 2009                 
  7823 afternoon                 Spring 2010               
  3623 evening                   Fall 2009                 
  3086 evening                   Spring 2010               
  7663 morning                   Fall 2009                 
  5602 morning                   Spring 2010
```

I have tried placing the CASEs in where and from clauses but seemed to not working out.

Thanks.

Comment: Please give some sample data to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(EMP_NUM) logins,

  Log_Time,

  Semester

FROM
  (SELECT emp_num,

    CASE

      WHEN TO_CHAR(login.log_in_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') > '12:00:00'

      AND TO_CHAR(login.log_in_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') <= '18:00:00'

      THEN 'Afternoon'

      WHEN TO_CHAR(login.log_in_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') > '18:00:00'

      AND TO_CHAR(login.log_in_time, 'HH24:MI:SS')  < '6:00:00'

      THEN 'Evening'

      ELSE 'Morning'

    END AS Log_Time,

    CASE
      WHEN login.log_in_date >= '15-AUG-09'

      AND login.log_in_date  <= '18-DEC-09'

      THEN 'Fall 2009'

      WHEN login.log_in_date >= '1-JAN-10'

      AND login.log_in_date  <= '15-MAY-10'

      THEN 'Spring 2010'

    END AS Semester

  FROM login
  )
GROUP BY Log_Time,

  Semester;
```